# c++ method sometimes returns unexpected high values

Tags: c++

I've traced a bug down to a function which should be returning float values between 20 and 100 or so, but is sometimes (1 time in 10) returning values much much higher than that. The problem exists when  I have an expression in the last line of the method, like this:

```
return snap(baseNumber, targets) + (octave * NOTES_PER_OCTAVE);
```

If I store the return value in a variable first, then return that variable, the problem goes away:

```
float ret = snap(baseNumber, targets) + (octave * NOTES_PER_OCTAVE);
return ret;
```

Here's the complete method:

```
static inline float octaveSnap(float number, std::vector<float>* targets){
    static const int NOTES_PER_OCTAVE = 12;
    int octave = number / NOTES_PER_OCTAVE;
    float baseNumber = number - (octave * NOTES_PER_OCTAVE);
    float ret = snap(baseNumber, targets) + (octave * NOTES_PER_OCTAVE);
    return ret;
}
```

and here's 'snap':

```
// given a single value and a list of values (a scale), return the member of the list which is closest to the single value 
static inline float snap(float number, std::vector<float>* targets){
    float ret;
    float leastDistance = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<targets->size(); i++){
        float distance = targets->at(i) - number;
        if(distance < 0){
            distance = -distance;
        }
        if(leastDistance == -1){
            leastDistance = distance;
        }
        if(distance < leastDistance){
            leastDistance = distance;
            ret = targets->at(i);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I'm completely baffled by this. Any idea why the first explodes and the second works perfectly?

Comment: This looks to me like memory corruption (e.g. a buffer overrun) from elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with promotion and/or RVO... I guess your best bet is to check generated assembly.

Comment: What is the return type of this function?

Comment: @Spidey and cha0site Added the complete method in my question.

Comment: It's difficult to say...
The return type of snap is float, but what for `(octave * NOTES_PER_OCTAVE)`?

I suppose that NOTES_PER_OCTAVE is a #define.
Remember that for defines if you declare them the following way

#define NOTES_PER_OCTAVE 1

they are implicitly int
but 
#define NOTES_PER_OCTAVE 1.0

they are implicitly `double` and not float.
I suggest to avoid the #defines because they are evil and instead use `static const` variables.

Comment: as a suggestion, always pass std containers by reference not by pointer.

Comment: Thanks @linello. NOTES_PER_OCTAVE is a static const int, defined inside the method.

Comment: @molbdnilo added 'snap' to question body.

Comment: @morgancodes: you have not provided "snap" method, so it is not possible to help you. Unless "targets" parameter is optional and can be `NULL`, it should be passed by reference. If `targets` is never modified by function, it should be passed by const reference. You also haven't provided function body for the method that calls `snap`. For example, if function in question returns `float&`, it'll behave exactly in the way you describe.

Comment: @morgancodes: "added 'snap' " You should pass `targets` by const reference. You don't need pointers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `snap()` the local variable `ret` is never initialized so if the input vector is either zero-sized or the "found" element is the first one then your return value is unspecified.

Try modifying snap to be:

```
static inline float snap(float number, std::vector<float>* targets){
    float ret = 0;
    float leastDistance = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<targets->size(); i++){
        float distance = targets->at(i) - number;
        if(distance < 0){
            distance = -distance;
        }
        if(leastDistance == -1){
            leastDistance = distance;
            ret = targets->at(i);
        }
        else if(distance < leastDistance){
            leastDistance = distance;
            ret = targets->at(i);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and see if that fixes things.

Edit: I realized this doesn't address why adding a temporary variable appears to fix things in the original question. The uninitialized `ret` will *probably* take on whatever value is left on the stack: this, of course, is unspecified and system/platform dependent. When a new local variable is added to store the result of `snap()`, however, this shifts the stack such that `ret` has a different position, most likely, a different uninitialized value. The return result is still "wrong" but it may simply appear "less wrong" due to whatever uninitialized value `ret` has.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you than you. The gremlin in my code was ME! The issue wasn't actually that I wasn't initializing ret, it was that ret wasn't being set when the "found" element was the first element. Changed `distance < leastDistance` to `distance <= leastDistance` fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that when you use the temp variable the problem only appears to go away and that either you're accidentally doing `targets[<foo>]` inside `snap` or you use it correctly but rarely run off the end, returning garbage.

EDIT for comment:

I should elaborate a bit: `targets` is a *pointer* to `vector` so using `[]` on it will select one of several vectors, NOT elements from the vector. That said I can't understand how you could call `.at` on such a pointer, so I suspect the code in your program is not the code you showed us.

Comment: How nice it must be to have a functioning psychic debugger! I am indeed doing 'targets[<foo>]' inside 'snap'. I've changed that to 'targets.at()'. This may make for better/safer C++ style, but doesn't fix my bug. The use of the temp variable very clearly changes the behavior. I've gone back and forth several times and verified that things work correctly when I use the temp variable and fail when I don't.

Comment: I'm messing something up, but it's not being confused about what a pointer is. I'm actually doing 'targets->at(<foo>)' inside 'snap', but wrote targets.at() in a (failed) attempt to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you're only interacting with a single `targets` vector over a single `octaveSnap` call, your function signature should be `static float octaveSnap(float number, std::vector<float>& targets)`, or `static float octaveSnap(float number, const std::vector<float>& targets)` if the function doesn't alter `targets`. Also, most compilers don't pay much attention to `inline` anymore.

Comment: Thanks @MikeDeSimone In this case, is the reference vs pointer thing a matter of style and readability, or does it have an effect on behavior?

Comment: It has an effect on behavior. Passing by reference is the same as passing by pointer at the machine-code level, so there is no performance difference, but it's entirely different at the language level. When a function is passed a reference, it will not misinterpret that as an array. So my recommendation is "prefer passing objects by reference unless you want to potentially pass an array of objects."

Comment: The flag is: if you're really passing an array, then most likely there's another parameter specifying the length of the array (the exception being something like `const char*`, which uses a null terminator to specify length). Thus a `std::vector` is considered an object, not an array, since all the pointer and length information is internal to it.